# Finding 4 Unknowns in terms of constants

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

This might be harder without explaining the problem i'm trying to solve, but i'm not sure that i could explain it clearly, or how much it would help.

Consider the equations:
$$k=wa+xe=yb+zf \\ f=b+d \\ a=c+e$$

Here $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are constant integers and: $$GCD(a,b,c,d,e,f)=1$$ $w,x,y,z$ are also integers.Given values for these 6 constants, I want to be able to find $w,x,y, z$ (or find a way to determine if they are odd or even) for the smallest possible value of $k$.

I would love any kind of help solving this, or even knowing if this problem is possible to solve with the current information, or if i need to look for a different way to go about this problem. I'm fairly sure the problem cannot be solved the way i'm trying to, but at the very least, I would like confirmation from someone more capable than me.

Comment: I edited for readability of the math equations. Please check if it means what you have asked.

Comment: Yeah i think that's right, thanks. I wasn't sure how to do all that

Comment: You need two more equations to be given connecting w,x,y and z. One equation is less (3) due to requirement of solution ( of 4) in positive integers.

Comment: @Narasimham I think OP wants a parametrization of all integer solutions $w,x,y,z.$[There are a three parameter family of these.]

Comment: Something i feel very stupid for leaving out, is that i'm only interested in the values of w,x,y,z for the lowest possible value of either side of the first equation

Comment: You are making many changes to your question, and it still is not clear. What do you mean by "the lowest possible value of either side of the first equation"? My solution lets you choose $w$ and $x$ in any way you choose, so just make them "small." Perhaps you should ask the question again, this time with all requirements clearly stated in the question.

Comment: I've changed the post to try and describe it as well as i can. I apologize it was so unclear to start with and hope i haven't left anything else out

Answer (score 0):

Equations 2 and 3 are the only ones mentioning $d,e$ and can be viewed as saying your initial values for the constants satisfy those equations. I don't see much advantage in substituting them into the first equation.

That said, the first equation 
$$aw+ex=by+fz \tag{1}$$
may be parametrized, provided you're willing at first to find $w_0,x_0,y_0,z_0$ such that $$aw_0+ex_0=1,\\ by_0+fz_0=1.\tag{2}$$ There unfortunately is not a simple "formula" for these solutions, but they can be found using the Euclidean algorithm in case $a,e,b,f$ happen to be large.

Now let the common value of the sides of $(1)$ be called $k,$ and then note that equations $(2)$ may be multiplied each by $k$ to get initial solutions for $(1),$ and using the results about solving single linear equations we get a parametrization for $(1)$ by means of, using $s,t$ for arbitrary (independent) integers, along with the integer $k$ denoting the common value of the sides of $(1),$

$$w=w_0k+es,\\ x=x_0k-as,\\ y=y_0k+ft,\\ z=z_0k-bt.$$

Answer (score 0):

Your phrase "$a,b,c,d,e,f$ ... have no common factors" is ambiguous. I'll assume that it means that $a$ and $e$ are relatively prime to each other, as are $b$ and $f$. That's all I'll need for my following analysis.

Of your three equations, the second and third merely relate your constants so that $c$ and $d$, which are not even in the first equation. are determined from the other constants. So you really have just one equation relating your four variables. I'm sure you know that means that three of those variables can be chosen freely and that determines the fourth variable.

However, you have the added restriction that the variables are all integers. But that does not change the solution much.

Let's say you choose the values of $w$ and $x$ arbitrarily from the integers. Since $a$ and $e$ are relatively prime, [Bézout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) says that you could end up with any integer value on the left hand side of your equation. Let's call that value $j$. Then we want to continue solving

$$j=yb+zf$$

Since $b$ and $f$ are relatively prime, by Bézout's identity again and its corollaries there is a unique number which I'll call $b^{-1}$ that is the multiplicative inverse of $b$ modulo $f$. In other words,

$$f \mid (b\cdot b^{-1}-1) \qquad \text{and} \qquad 0\le b^{-1}<f$$

We now have many choices for $y$, namely

$$y=b^{-1}j+kf$$

for any integral value of $k$. The value of $z$ is then determined.

---

In summary, you can choose $w$ and $x$ freely from all integers. You also freely choose an integer $k$. The value of $y$ is then taken to be

$$y=b^{-1}(wa+xe)+kf$$

(Remember that $b^{-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $b$ modulo $f$.) $z$ is then determined by

$$z=\frac{wa+xe-yb}f$$

and is guaranteed to be an integer.

Comment: Sorry i'm horrible at being clear in explanations. I meant that The greatest common divisor of the set of a,b,c,d,e,f is 1